# find a where $\sum_{n=n(a)}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{(2+n^a)}{n}$ converges and absolutely converges

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, summation

Study $a$ so that the series convergences and absolute convergences 
I just know that $a$ is positive

I applied the **ratio test**, I've found that $0<a<1$

I have no idea for absolute convergence.

Thanks a lot for looking and helping.

Comment: What is $n(a)$?

Comment: $n=n(a)$ when I'll find $a$ so that the series converges or absolutely converges, then I'll find this $n=n(a)$, where the sum start

Answer (score 0):

Consider the absolute value $|(-1)^n \frac{2 + n^a}{n}| = \frac{2 + n^a}{n}$ for $a > 0$ we can say that $\frac{2 + n^a}{n} \ge \frac{n^a}{n} = \frac{1}{n^{1 - a}}$ and such a series is divergent hence your series doesn't converge absolutely

Comment: I need a value of a where is the series is convergent and I used ratio test, but it is not absolutely convergent in general?

Comment: If $a$ is positive yes, it's not absolutely convergent in general

Comment: the exercise tells that $\forall a>0$ exists $n(a)$ so that every term of the series is defined.

Comment: Then I have to find $a$ (positives values) that the series is a) convergent and b) absolute convergent

Comment: @stefanoferrari if $a > 0$ then $1 - a < 1$ hence $\sum \frac{1}{n^{1 - a}}$ is divergent

Comment: Ok, so if $1-a < 1$  the series is divergent for $a>0$ . I hope that I have done right thinking about this series as an approximation of this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2631576/find-a-so-that-sum-n-na-infty-1n-r-2na-has-a-convergence-and

Comment: initial series is absolutely divergent for $a > 0$

Comment: Is My approximation of that series into this topic's series, wrong then?

Comment: @stefanoferrari Honestly, I don't understand how these topics are related to each other. If you assume that $P(n) = n$ then the degree of $Q$ should be 2...

Comment: Yes but when you going to do the limits to $\infty$ you got something like: $\frac{n^{N-1}}{n^N} \sim  \frac{1}{n}$

Comment: if: R=P/Q
$P(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} a_i n^i  $ 

$Q(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{N} b_i n^i $ 
for $x$ to $\infty$ we have:
$P(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{N-1} a_i n^i  $ $ \sim n^{N-1}$

$Q(n) = \sum_{i=0}^{N} b_i n^i $ $ \sim n^N$
then: 
$\sum_{n=n(a)}^\infty (-1)^n R (2+n^a) \sim \sum_{n=n(a)}^\infty (-1)^n  \frac{2+n^a}{n}$